# Grails data sorting

Tags: sorting, grails

Populate data like

```
[[vaccineName:Typhoid, dueDate:2016-08-01 00:00:00.0], 
 [vaccineName:MMR, dueDate:2016-03-01 00:00:00.0], 
 [vaccineName:Hepatitis A, dueDate:2023-09-01 00:00:00.0], 
 [vaccineName:IPV, dueDate:2016-02-01 00:00:00.0], 
 [vaccineName:DT, dueDate:2016-01-01 00:00:00.0], 
 [vaccineName:Influenza, dueDate:2015-12-01 00:00:00.0]]
```

Now how can sort data according to dueDate. I want show this data either ascending or descending..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sort Javascript Object Array By Date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10123953/sort-javascript-object-array-by-date)

Comment: Does that answer your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the short answer is

```
 list.sort{ it.dueDate }
```

Answer (score 0):

Where do you have that data?

You can use sort method: [Groovy sort](http://www.groovy-lang.org/groovy-dev-kit.html#_sorting)

In your case it will be something like this:

`list = list.sort{ a,b-> b.dueDate <=> a.dueDate }`